# MVC 4 Filter result - redirect or view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building MVC 4 application.
The authorization and exception handling is done using Filters.

In filter, I can either **redirect** user to my error page using `RedirectToRouteResult`
or **return view** of my error page using `ViewResult`.

Which variant is better in practice and why?

Comment: i used to redirect to action

Comment: Currently, I am redirecting to action (via Route) but I am not sure if this is good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Return View doesn't make a new requests, it just renders the view without changing URLs in the browser's address bar.

2.Return RedirectToAction makes a new requests and URL in the browser's address bar is updated with the generated URL by MVC.

3.Return Redirect also makes a new requests and URL in the browser's address bar is updated, but you have to specify the full URL to redirect

4.Between RedirectToAction and Redirect, best practice is to use RedirectToAction for anything dealing with your application actions/controllers. If you use Redirect and provide the URL, you'll need to modify those URLs manually when you change the route table.

5.RedirectToRoute redirects to a specific route defined in the Route table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move on error page with static data with limited messages then use `ViewResult` else use `RedirectToRouteResult` in this you can use as you want.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether there is any logic in an error action that populates a view model (e.g.setting the http status code) or you only have a static view. Of course you could move this logic to the filter, but this would prevent you from being able to redirect from another action that doesn't use the same filter.